# 3D convolution for preprocessing with Tensorflow

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, tensorflow, convolution

I built a neural network for pixel-wise classification of 3D-images.

The classification task is very simple and does not call for a convolutional network, instead I calculate a number of features (Gaussian, LoG, Sobel,etc...) and feed these together with the original value into a classical MLP. Since the calculation of this features is very slow and does not take advantage of my GPU, I thought a Tensorflow implementation might help:

First I read a binary file and create one batch with a 3D array and 1 channel:

```
data_dir="/Users/Me/Documents/Data/"
filenames = [os.path.join(data_dir,'File_%05d.bin' % i ) for i in range(100)]
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
Stack= BinChunkReader(filename_queue) #custom reader

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(tf.shape(Stack))) #outputs [1 100 100 100 1]
```

Then I create a 3D kernel using a custom function and define the 3D convolution:

```
kernel=np.ones((11,11,11,1,1),dtype='int32')
kernel[:,:,:,0,0]=Get3DKernel("LoG", Radius=6,Param=5) #custom function to produce a kernel

kernel_init=tf.constant(kernel)
TF_kernel=tf.get_variable('LoG_filter', initializer= kernel_init)
LoG=tf.nn.conv3d(Stack,TF_kernel,[1,1,1,1,1],"SAME")
```

but trying to run this

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(LoG)
```

produces the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Conv3D' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]

     [[Node: Conv3D_1 = Conv3D[T=DT_INT32, padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]](Reshape, LoG_filter/read)]]
```

The first question: what does this error mean and how do I implement a 3D convolution?

The second question: am I right in my assumption that implementing this in tensorflow (currently implemented with scikit-image) will be of advantage for the execution speed?

Comment: For your first question: Try defining `kernel=np.ones((11,11,11,1,1),dtype='float32')` instead

Comment: The error means there is no implementation of the Conv3D operation **for that specific combination of input types**. Your kernel is of type **int** but the kernels are available for floats and doubles (according to the error message, at least)

Comment: As per the speed question, it seems those operations are implemented on the CPU only (again, reading int the error message). Try and see if speed improves. Side question: are you using a GPU build of Tensorflow? Because `Registered Devices :[CPU]` in the error code seems to mean Tensorflow does not see your GPU...

Comment: Ok, switching to 'float32' in both Kernel and Stack works, thanks, and yet the convolution is now taking waaaay longer than the scikit image implementation. I am writing the code in my laptop, but will run the actual training in a computer with a GPU, no worries ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm putting together the solution in the comments in a more orderly fashion in case someone else stumbles on this question.

### Deciphering the error message:

Your error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Conv3D' with these attrs.  
Registered devices: [CPU], 
Registered kernels:
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
[[Node: Conv3D_1 = Conv3D[T=DT_INT32, padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]](Reshape, LoG_filter/read)]]
```

`No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Conv3D' with these attrs` means that the *attributes* you passed to the function call do not match any existing implementation for that function.

`Node: Conv3D_1 = Conv3D[`**`T=DT_INT32`**`, padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]](Reshape, LoG_filter/read)]` tells that for the `Conv3D` node in your graph that is raising the error, the input tensor has type `int32`.

```
Registered kernels:
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
```

tells that for the `Conv3D` operation there are available 2 implementations on your machine. One runs on your CPU and has as input a `float32` tensor (`DT_FLOAT`), while the other is also running on your CPU taking as input `float64` tensors (`DT_DOUBLE`).

**Note:** `Registered devices: [CPU],` seems to point at the fact that your Tensorflow **does not see your GPU** (did you install a CPU-only build of Tensorflow?).

### The answer to your questions:

> What does this error mean and how do I implement a 3D convolution?

I think the error has been explained enough in the previous section. You don't want to implement Conv3D on your own, but rather change the input type to something that already has an implementation. change the type of both `Stack` and `TF_kernel` to either `float32` or `float64` (e.g., define `kernel` with `kernel=np.ones((11,11,11,1,1),dtype='float32')`).

> Am I right in my assumption that implementing this in tensorflow (currently implemented with scikit-image) will be of advantage for the execution speed?

Hard to say. Since both implementations are CPU-only, I guess trying and seeing if things improve is the best option (it would be great if you could then update your question letting us know if it did speed up after all).
I'd also suggest to check if you're using the GPU Tensorflow build and, if not, switch to that one (that has a much higher chance to speed up your computation).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, sometimes this kind of errors are rather cryptic for me! I am currently writing and testing these programs in my laptop without a GPU (hence the lack of it in the error message). I will update my question with the result of this implementation as soon as I test it in our CUDA capable computer.

Comment: You're welcome! I think a big part of fighting Tensorflow is figuring out what all those codes mean (it's a rather verbose framework luckily), so I hope this will help with other errors in the future. Looking forward to the speed results! ;)